# Can't upload data from excel file to my database (mysql) using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I had a problem with uploading data from excel into my database I had an exception with this method :

```
private void ReadFileExcel(string filename)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@filename);
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
        ConnectMysqlBase.GetDBConnection();
        try
        {
            ConnectMysqlBase.connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO  userinformation VALUES (" + xlRange.Cells[2][1] + "," + xlRange.Cells[2][2] + "," + xlRange.Cells[2][3] + ","
                + xlRange.Cells[2][4] + "," + xlRange.Cells[2][5] + "," + xlRange.Cells[2][6] + "," + xlRange.Cells[2][7] + "," + xlRange.Cells[2][8] + "," + xlRange.Cells[2][9] + "," + xlRange.Cells[2][10] + "," + xlRange.Cells[2][11] + ") ;"
                , ConnectMysqlBase.connection);
            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            TableUser = dt;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            ConnectMysqlBase.connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

witch like : 
Unknown column 'System.__ComObject' in 'field list' !!!

Comment: You are trying to insert Cell objects, not their values

Comment: how can i insert their values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting a cell object, I am assuming that the cell object has a way to access the data inside it, you need to do this.

Instead of Cells[x][y] you need to do Cells[x][y].getValue() or whatever you have instead of getValue() to access the data inside.

Comment: yes i found how can i access to the value with : xlRange.Cells[1][1].Value.ToString(); thanks a lot